# Show ToolStripDropDown correctly

Tags: c#, winforms, toolstripdropdown

I want to show `ToolStripDropDown` in a way as `ComboBox`s dropdown is shown (or for example `DateTimePicker`s dropdown). So I wrote this code in my `Form`:

```cs
private readonly ToolStripDropDown _toolStripDropDown = new ToolStripDropDown
{
    TopLevel = false,
    CanOverflow = true,
    AutoClose = true,
    DropShadowEnabled = true
};

public Form1()
{
    InitializeComponent();
    var label = new Label{Text = "Ups"};
    var host = new ToolStripControlHost(label)
    {
        Margin = Padding.Empty,
        Padding = Padding.Empty,
        AutoSize = false,
        Size = label.Size
    };

    _toolStripDropDown.Size = label.Size;
    _toolStripDropDown.Items.Add(host);
    Controls.Add(_toolStripDropDown);
}

private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    _toolStripDropDown.Show(button1.Left, button1.Top + button1.Height);
}
```

When I click on button my `ToolStripDropDown` is shown but there is no shadow, no overflow, no autoclose. What am I doing wrong?

`Label` in `ToolStripControlHost` is for simplicity. I use WinForms and .NET 4.

**Update:**
[image: issue image]

As you can see dropdown "Ups" doesn't overflow window, doesn't has shadow (`ComboBox`s dropdown has both) and even when I clicked on `ComboBox` dropdown "Ups" is still visible.

Comment: Your question is somewhat unclear. Can you explain more about, what do you mean by: `but there is no shadow, no overflow, no autoclose. What am I doing wrong?` Update the question if required.

Comment: Thank you for reply. I updated my question and hope it is more understandable now.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You are parenting your control to the Form, which restricts it to that parent's `ClipRectangle`.

Remove the `TopLevel` designation, remove the parenting, calculate the position in screen coordinates, and finally, show the menu:

```
    private readonly ToolStripDropDown _toolStripDropDown = new ToolStripDropDown
    {
        //TopLevel = false,
        CanOverflow = true,
        AutoClose = true,
        DropShadowEnabled = true
    };

    public Form4()
    {
        InitializeComponent();

        var label = new Label { Text = "Ups" };
        var host = new ToolStripControlHost(label)
        {
            Margin = Padding.Empty,
            Padding = Padding.Empty,
            AutoSize = false,
            Size = label.Size
        };

        _toolStripDropDown.Size = label.Size;
        _toolStripDropDown.Items.Add(host);
        //Controls.Add(_toolStripDropDown);
    }

    private void button1_Click(Object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Point pt = this.PointToScreen(button1.Location);
        pt.Offset(0, button1.Height);
        _toolStripDropDown.Show(pt);

    }
```

Comment: Really thank you. I didn't realize this restriction. Works great now.